# Cannot sort filtered lists in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Basically I am having a lot of trouble sorting a filter list in a Kendo grid.

I am using Kendo version 2015.3.111.

Using the below function (Defined in grid creation)  no errors are thrown, but the grid filter list does not get populated, it is empty.

The line "filterMultiCheck.checkSource.data(filterMultiCheck.checkSource.view().toJSON());" is showing as undefined

```
, filterMenuInit: function (e) {
            var multiCheck = this.thead.find("[data-field=" + e.field + "]").data("kendoFilterMultiCheck")
            if (multiCheck) {
                console.log("multicheck not null");
                multiCheck.container.empty();
                multiCheck.checkSource.sort({ field: e.field, dir: "asc" });
                multiCheck.checkSource.data(multiCheck.checkSource.view().toJSON());
                multiCheck.createCheckBoxes();
            }
```

}

I have integrated this sorting functionality in a previous application, but that was on a 2016 version of Kendo, not sure if there is a big difference in available functionality between 2015 and 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo UI landscape is ever changing.

You will want to review the "Kendo UI Release History" at
https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history

Kendo UI R3 2016 has this Grid "New" bullet item which may be pertinent to your issue

- Expose sort, filter and page events on for the Grid